# Trouble with my code (IF , ELSE)

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

Having technical issues with this line of code.
I want it to first calculate the BMI than determine if weight is over 25 tell patient that
they are overweight. If under 18.5 they are underweight.
Cant Seem To get the function right.

```
var calculate 
var test;
calculate = document.getElementById("answer");
calculate.innerHTML =  (weight/(height*height))* 703;

if(calculate > 25)
{
calculate = document.getElementById("answer06");
calculate.innerHTML = "you are fat";
}
else if(calculate < 18.5)
{
calculate = document.getElementById("answer06");
calculate.innerHTML = "you are to skinny";
}
```

Comment: `calculate` in your case is a HTML element, not a number.

Comment: @Marty: Make that an answer

Comment: so would I change if(calculate > 25)  to if(answer > 25) ?

Comment: You also have a missing semicolon on line 1 `var calculate;`

Comment: @ThomasSebastian JavaScript actually has a nasty little feature where lines [automatically have a semicolon added](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi).

Comment: Yeah it does Marty. Just better to keep up with good coding practices. Don't you agree? :)

Comment: @ThomasSebastian Of course, just wanted to flag that the lack of `;` would not affect the code whatsoever in its current state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var bmi = (weight/(height*height))* 703;
calculate.innerHTML = bmi;

if(bmi > 25)
```

**Update:**

```
var bmi = (weight/(height*height))* 703;
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = bmi;

if (bmi > 25)
{
    document.getElementById("answer06").innerHTML = "you are fat";
}
else if (bmi < 18.5)
{
    document.getElementById("answer06").innerHTML = "you are too skinny";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Going to try this out now.

Comment: Maybe I am still a Noob at this but how can I set it up using your code plus mine? And have it show up in <div id="answer">-----</div> on page.

Comment: Yeah after I looked awhile at code I realize how It was done. Thank you so much tho. Really am greatful.